# Get values from multiple excels based on a specific string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get values from multiple excels and create a new excel. I want to get the value based on a specific string.The value is next to the given string but some excels have merged cells. Below you can see two samples and the output that I want

[image: Sample 1]
[image: Sample 2]
[image: Output]

I get ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Any help?

```
files = glob.glob(os.path.join("/fafasfasf,"*.xlsx"))
i=0

data = pd.DataFrame({"bananas":[]})
data1 = pd.DataFrame({"apples":[]})

for f in files:
     df=pd.read_excel(f)
     df=df.fillna(method='ffill',axis=1)
     
         
     
     mask = np.hstack([np.repeat(False, len(df)).reshape(-1, 1),(df.values == 'bananas')[:, :-1]])
     mask1 = np.hstack([np.repeat(False, len(df)).reshape(-1, 1),(df.values == 'apples')[:, :-1]])  
     
    
     x=df.values[mask]
     z=df.values[mask1]
     
     
     x.tolist()
     z.tolist()
    
     
     x= remove_values_from_list(x,'bananas')
     z= remove_values_from_list(z, 'apples')
    
     
     data.at[i,"bananas"]=x
     data1.at[i,"apples"]=z
  
          
     i=i+1

stack=pd.concat([data,data1],axis=1)

stack.to_excel("dadafg.xlsx")
```

Comment: `.at` is for setting a single element, while `x` and `z` returned from the masks can contain multiple values ?

Comment: Any ideas how can I insert the second value?

Comment: Create some sample data input and show us the expected output

Comment: I have just uploaded an image that shows the sample and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a demo (two excel) read as df1 and df2
[image: df1 and df2 for two demo excel file]

```
df1:
    0   1       2   3       4   5   6   7
0   a   b       c   d       a   b   c   d
1   b   bananas NaN 3000    b   ds  g   f
2   c   as      as  as      c   apples  100 as
3   d   as      as  as      d   as  as  as

df2:
    0   1       2       3   4   5       6   7
6   a   b       c       d   a   b       c   d
7   b   bananas 12340   d   b   ds      g   f
8   c   as      as      as  c   apples  500 as
9   d   as      as      as  d   as      as  as
```

You can see pandas reading excel from a merge cell will results NaN except the first one.

So loop all df to find value from 'bananas' and 'apples' 's rightside (skip NaN).

```
res = {}
res['bananas'] = []
res['apples'] = [] 
for dd in [df1, df2]:
    for word in ['bananas', 'apples']:
        #use np.where to get 'bananas' position
        r, c = np.where(dd == word)
        #get same row, next column by a shift to get a value(+n)
        got_value = False
        cc = c[0]
        while not got_value:
            val = dd.iat[r[0], cc+1]
            if pd.isnull(val):
                cc+=1
            else:
                res[word].append(val)
                got_value = True
```

Convert result to pandas.DataFrame by `pd.DataFrame(res)`.

```
    bananas apples
0   3000    100
1   12340   500
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but excels are not consistent.

Comment: @Tsorts Could you create two inconsistent excel samples? I will create a new excel base on my code I posted.

Comment: Sorry for the late response I have uploaded two  samples and the output that I am trying to get. I have also changed the code because I am trying to deal with merged cells.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I use your code in for loop so I can read all excel files from a folder I get "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Comment: `dd ` in your code must dataframe, and “bananas” and “apples” must in your every excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who knows what is going wrong with the code I have posted?

When I use it in a single Dataframe it works.